# find the number of a digit can exist in another number

Tags: javascript

I have a number and a master number. How do I check how many times can x exist in the number?

```
  const x = 2
  const masterNumber = 5
```

so here, 2 can exist 2 times in 5. i.e. 2+2 < 5.

```
  const x = 3
  const masterNumber = 5
```

here, 3 exist once. cos 3+3> 5.

```
  const x = 1
  const masterNumber = 5
```

can exist 5 times. cos 1+1+1+1+1=5

I considered doing masterNumber / x but for e.g. for x=2, it returns 2.5

Comment: just round down..?

Comment: `Math.floor(masterNumber/x)` (A quick search on SO for round down to nearest integer would have yielded the result)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.floor()`:

```js
const x = 3;
const masterNumber = 5;
var numTimes = Math.floor(masterNumber / x);
console.log(numTimes);
```

The floor of the quotient will, by definition, be the number of times the whole integer denominator can fit into the numerator, excluding the fractional remainder.

Answer (score -1):

You need to round down that number using [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```js
$('#x, #master').change(function () {
  let result = parseInt($('#master').val()) / parseInt($('#x').val());
  let finalResult = Math.floor(result);
  
  console.log(result, finalResult);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
X: <input type="number" id="x"/><br/>
Master number: <input type="number" id="master"/>
```